# How to display the ouput window from an add-in?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, vs-extensibility

I currently have a visual studio add-in and have created a new output window pane which I can write text to successfully.  However, when the output window is not open or it is minimised then it doesn't open (popup) when I call the Activate() method on the pane. Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Comment: I'd say it isn't typically very appropriate for an add-in to automatically switch windows.  Leave it up to the user.

Comment: @Hans - It might be useful in a case similar to a Find where, after the search, the results window is given focus and you want to direct the user's attention there. No?

Comment: @Hans what if his add-in magically does all your work?

Comment: Its for displaying the results from a build server and so I would think it would be appreciated if the user was shown the results.  Similar to the Build results which are displayed when a local build is run in VS.  I still expect the user to develop their solution themselves ;o)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you created your Add-in using the Add-in wizard you should have an Exec() method like below.  I have added two lines that cause the Output window to open and become visible regardless whether it was originally closed or minimized.  I tested this in VS2008 and VS2010.

```
public void Exec(string commandName, vsCommandExecOption executeOption, ref object varIn, ref object varOut, ref bool handled)
{
    handled = false;
    if(executeOption == vsCommandExecOption.vsCommandExecOptionDoDefault)
    {
        if(commandName == "AddinTest.Connect.AddinTest")
        {
            // Find the output window.
            Window outputWindow = _applicationObject.Windows.Item(Constants.vsWindowKindOutput);
            // Show the window. (You might want to make sure outputWindow is not null here...)
            outputWindow.Visible = true;

            handled = true;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This was useful in a VSPackage as well, so thanks for that. It was driving me crazy! The code needs to be modified slightly, to use _dte.Windows instead of _applicationObject.